# Is it possible to encrypt data in perl using Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA and decrypt data in php?

Tags: php, perl

I try to encrypt data in perl and decrypt data in php using Crypt::OpenSSL:RSA. 
I am able to decrypt in perl but get NULL in php.

perl code:

```
use strict;
use MIME::Base64;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

my $string = '123';

my $key_string = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA2n9QlRt3ERZXt6CQ5ufb
eKIlzaJFqr7LxgxiRSy/ZdMnxvCdRoKtW4JbVM62WaEBuOVZIxlJRYRTplloDl9l
7yksxEfN5/AosIJzOPqjj1U1ICvoFS1ORS/8FwAqBd3HeL8BW3gIH+03WTh+bKE/
65u7hyTEi/bb3k1JtxUVSKI04EovCZVivR/nhAZ7lJrjhW23vmhTwlIoIijZfOre
ctE00rcJ9I5KY4V4djQM8mDGFWQTNrdBku+DpGt4//lw/i5w0/MCr9mHqSw3Nxty
/PnMG7dpiA+WjVA9W1TYCVcRZBD+Wsd3OjXxgl46OZYdI5dKYNLKE7BUMccEJj9l
eQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

my $public = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($key_string);
$string = $public->encrypt($string);

$string = MIME::Base64::encode_base64($string);

print $string;
```

php code:

```
<?php
    $encrypted = 'ZkEVc2US6/mqeix3409VYXSTmJtycVLxXztsKpCFpbb6Adp3MBRfYL4nblsWLND+17xaLhVqk4+h ZPw97gzAqlp8YNPA4vgCVdzamq84+kVd7Ykqot9UcDq9zRSpo7S/8EenZO8Cu9OlAwvTavb2pSnX z0w9a9mJqmIJ+zYtao6L1tV3+WlcMIYix9vaIiWU5qZigjNAlff+wT20pEh7Lqu2iAsd1h8aKt5l 3NBRqHG9M0WqTdhzrqk0Rvb9i/a2Zoo7XWC/jz9OR8FaThCM7Gyw8+jWL+z+aL2qveeAPW9e7Pwa GSk1SibTs1L0lTeQk8FmjtC2IW1j7Qn8NzUcZA==';
    $encrypted = base64_decode($encrypted);
    $key_content = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
    $private_key_res = openssl_get_privatekey($key_content);
    openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $private_key_res);
    var_dump($decrypted);
?>
```

And I get NULL in PHP

Comment: This looks familiar somehow. I think I've seen a similar question.

Comment: Please show the PHP code you are using as well. You can [edit] your question. For this kind of thing, we need a [mcve].

Comment: I solved the problem with add
`$public->use_sslv23_padding();`

Comment: You should post that as an answer with a bit of explanation for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem with add $public->use_sslv23_padding();
the encrypt data can decrypt in php.